# Writing a zsh script that goes in order

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh

I am using Big Sur and I am trying to write a script that will make a package run (the package is XSPEC, a spectral fitting package from NASA), and then run commands run in that package. I start with `XSPEC` to open the package, and then I want to run `data 1:1 /Users/me/Desktop/Drive/my\ data/spectrum2.pha` My issue is that if I just put the two lines spaced with an enter, the second line doesn't run, because I assume that the first line doesn't terminate until I quit out of the package. Whenever XSPEC is done starting up, it prints `XSPEC version: 12.11.1   Build Date/Time: Thu Jul  1 04:09:17 2021  XSPEC12>` (is prints that in three separate lines). Is there a way to make an if statement that will go to the next step once the previous lines are printed?

Comment: Appending a '&' to the command signals the shell to excute the command as a background process, and immediately proceed to the next command without waiting for any kind of exit status. That is why the second command _seems_ to start before the first. It is not. The first simply becomes a background process which may or may not finish it's own startup sequence while the shell is already moved on to the next step of the script. Having more details on which OS, which application, etc, would be helpful in finding out how to detect when the first command is in a state ready for the next.

Comment: (And yes, I did search Google for "XSPEC", which gave multiple results, mainly a spectral package from NASA, which seems to fit. But better if you are specific, instead of us making blind guesses.)

Comment: Yes, I am using the XSPEC spectral fitting from NASA, and I am using Big Sur on my Mac. Whenever XSPEC is done starting up, it prints ```XSPEC version: 12.11.1
 Build Date/Time: Thu Jul  1 04:09:17 2021

XSPEC12>``` (is prints that in three separate lines). Is there a way to make an if statement that will go to the next step once the previous lines are printed?

Comment: Please edit your question to present that information, either instead of or in addition to answering in comments. Some here may not or have no desire to read through comments to find that information, and may skip the question entirely if it's not immediately apparent and clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [XSPEC documentation](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/xanadu/xspec/manual/node17.html):

> XSPEC is a command-driven, interactive program. You will see a prompt `XSPEC12>` whenever input is required.

That means, the XSPEC program is not intended to be executed the way you are trying. Note also the rest of the paragraph:

> Command recall and inline editing are available using the arrow keys. XSPEC uses Tcl as its user interface, providing looping, conditionals, file I/O, and so on. For further details of the Tcl syntax, consult appendix A, and links therein.

In particular, the fact that XSPEC uses Tcl. Tcl is, itself, a scripting language. And the wording from the documentation suggests that you can write and use a Tcl script to direct/control the XSPEC program and it's operation, rather than trying to use `zsh` to execute XSPEC non-interactively. Instead, write a Tcl script to load the data set, do the processing, and output the results.

You will need to read the XSPEC manual for more information on how to do this. The manual also provides links and information on how to learn/use Tcl for this task.

Edit to add: It also just now occurred to me that the entire `data ...` line *is* an XSPEC command (in Tcl). As such, it is *not* a `zsh` command at all. So the way you are trying to do it is entirely wrong, anyhow. There are several ways you can load/execute the XSPEC `data ...` command to XSPEC, including an external script file or shell redirection. Again, read the XSPEC documentation for how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The clean way is to figure out if there is any way of knowing that this `XSPEC`, whatever that is, has finished loading. Since you haven't given us any detail at all about what that is, I am afraid I can't help on that front.

The simple, hacky way is to tell your script to wait a few seconds between launching the first command in the background and launching the next. The tool for that is `sleep`, so you want something like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh

XSPEC &
## Now wait 5 seconds
sleep 5
## And continue
data 1:1 /Users/me/Desktop/Drive/my\ data/spectrum2.pha
wait # for XSPEC to finish
```

You can play around with the `sleep` time to find the shortest value that consistently works.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate input to an interactive terminal application with an [Expect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html) script, which for MacOS can be installed via [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/expect).

You will want something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn XSPEC

expect "XSPEC12>"
send -- "data 1:1 /Users/me/Desktop/Drive/my\ data/spectrum2.pha"

# Some expectation which can detect the completion of the previous step
# Further Commands
```

Comment: `expect` is, itself, a Tcl-enabled application, so there is no need to use it when the `XSPEC` application is also a Tcl-enabled application, which can accept a Tcl script without going in to interactive mode.

Comment: [This page](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/xanadu/xspec/xspec11/tcl/tcl.html) in the manual implies that the application can indeed load a Tcl script, but to do so, one must type in a handful of commands interactively. The `expect` solution allows for fully automated operation. It really depends on whether the question asker just wants to automate a tedious task (Likely) or wants to run this autonomously as part of a larger pipeline.

Comment: Likewise, [this page from the manual](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/xanadu/xspec/manual/node24.html) specifically gives instructions for running a script directly from the command line. (And notes the file extension `.xcm` expected, as well, rather than the Tcl standard `.tcl`.) This may matter should there be a new version released, and the prompt becomes "XSPEC13>" instead of "XSPEC12>", which would break on an `expect` solution.

Comment: And yes, you could also use `expect`'s pattern matching to avoid that, too. But so long as the capability to simply pass a script name to the command exists, why jump through an extra hoop?

Comment: I had a look around for something like that, my apologies, I must have missed it (I actually couldn't find any evidence that XSPEC had a command line interface at all)

Comment: The manual is large, but has a lot of information. Not even I looked too deep at it, only enough to figure out "should we answer this here, or direct the OP to RTFM/research more?" In addition, `expect` is a useful tool for many applications, which your answer may still help other users seeking solutions that do not include a Tcl interpreter, but come across this question while researching. So it's still a useful answer.